# How to show an embedded image using localhost node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to node.js and trying to figure out how to show my image that's coded into my html file, when I'm running the .js file through node.

My image code in the HTML is in the header:

```
<center><img src="401kpiggybank.png" alt="Logo"></center>
```

and the code in my server.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
const PORT = 8080;

fs.readFile('<long file path here>', function (err, html){

    if (err) throw err; 

    http.createServer(function(request, response){
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(html)
        response.end();
    }).listen(PORT)

})
```

I know the html page is working, because all other elements (it's a 401k calculator) are displaying correctly, it's just the .png file I am having troubles with.

I have tried googling it and tried to get express working, but I couldn't get it to show. Also, the image is in the same directory as the html and js files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: My failed attempts at express are as follows:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var imgDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/images');
app.use(express.static(imgDir));
```

For this attempt, I added the image file into a folder called images. I then got an error when I ran it saying `Cannot find module 'express'`. I did npm express and everything seemed okay, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Final edit: I tried changing the PATH of node, as well as moving the express module folder into the folder where my html/js files are.
Still returning errors. As for now I'm giving up on this and moving on.

I'll still leave the topic open.

Comment: Do you wish to  use [tag:expressjs]? It offers some functionality to add certain directories as static directories so you could request them from a browser directly using it's static path

Comment: I tired to get express working with examples I found online, but I was getting errors.

Comment: Can you show your attempt with expressjs, together with the errors you had?

Comment: I added edits to OP.

Comment: Do you have a package.json in your working folder? And if you did, did you do `npm install -D express` to add express as a dependency and install it inside node-modules, so you can require it? For the static one, you can (optionally I think) define which path points to your static directory like `app.use( '/images', express.static( imgDir ) )`

Comment: I ran npm install -D express and it installed, but still getting same error. Do I need to move the express module into the folder with the html/js files? 

Also can I just leave the png file in the same folder as the html/js?

Comment: well, you have to run the command where the package.json for your project is located. If you don't have a package.json yet, you can create a new one by using `npm init` and answering the wizards questions. Then you either have to manually add expressjs as a dependency, or execute the install command again for express